# Chrome/Edge not sending preflight OPTIONS requests cross origin while Firefox works

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https, http-headers, preflight

I'm sending `Authorization` token in the header to both the same-origin and cross origin servers. I have set up the server to respond to `OPTIONS` requests with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://10.26.97.22:10251 (this is dynamically set to the origin of the request)
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: keep-alive
```

The requests on Firefox work (the above is what's shown for Firefox's response header.) and the `POST` requests that triggered the preflight requests go through no problem.

However, neither Chrome nor Edge work with no error reported. Just failed requests saying `net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED`.

Below is the success response to `POST` requests that actually go through on Firefox:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 00:05:49 GMT
Content-type: application/json
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://10.26.97.22:10251 (again, this is dynamically set)
Vary: Origin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; font-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self'; connect-src *; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';base-uri 'self';form-action 'self';
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I tried clearing cache, opening the site in incognito mode, as well as start chrome with web security disabled. Only worked when web security is disabled.

I compared the preflight requst headers between regular Chrome and Firefox, see below:

Regular Chrome:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.26.97.30:10261
Origin: https://10.26.97.22:10251
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Firefox:

```
OPTIONS /homepage HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.26.97.30:10261
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: https://10.26.97.22:10251
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it might be happening because I didn't terminate the header properly. Even though I've indicated that the `OPTIONS` response has no content (`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content`), it still needs the extra empty line to terminate the header section. It seems like Firefox is a little bit more forgiving than Chromimum-based browsers. Added an empty line after the last header printout solved the issue.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages